# Update_or_insert (merge into) not working in Oracle

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, insert-update

**What's wrong with my UPDATE_OR_INSERT code below?**

```sql
MERGE INTO EMAIL_LIST d USING (SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' EMAIL) s
    ON (d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE SET d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (EMAIL) VALUES (s.EMAIL);
```

Given the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE EMAIL_LIST ( 
    EMAIL VARCHAR2 (100)  NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE EMAIL_LIST
    ADD CONSTRAINT PK_EMAIL_LIST PRIMARY KEY ( EMAIL ) ;
```

**Error**

> Error report:
>
> SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of things;

You need to select the constant from something, in Oracle's case, DUAL;

```
MERGE INTO EMAIL_LIST d 
USING 
    (SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL) s
ON (d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (EMAIL) VALUES (s.EMAIL);
```

Also, you cannot match on d.EMAIL and at the same time update it. Your line;

```
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL
```

Doesn't really make sense anyway, since d.EMAIL is already equal to s.EMAIL or the match wouldn't happen. Remove the `WHEN MATCHED` and you'll end up with the working;

```
MERGE INTO EMAIL_LIST d 
USING 
    (SELECT 'foo@gmail.com' EMAIL FROM DUAL) s
ON (d.EMAIL = s.EMAIL)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (EMAIL) VALUES (s.EMAIL);
```